# how to import components from a Stencil library in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

I just created :

- a stencilJS component library named "my-lib" using the "npm init stencil" wizard, and
  built it successfully
- a ionic react app using "ionic start myApp tabs"

Now I'd like to use the default "my-component" aka MyComponent from my-lib , so I

- added `"my-lib" : "../my-lib"` in the app package.json dependencies and "npm install" ed it
- tried many import combinations to reach the MyComponent in the Components namespace, the "best" being

```
    import {Components} from 'my-lib'; 
    import MyComponent = Components.MyComponent;
```

where the code completion in Visual Studio Code is happy, but I get :

`` SyntaxError: C:\Dev\TypeScript\oacs-react\src\pages\Tab1.tsx: `import =` is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript
Please consider using `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.> ``

What's the proper way of solving this, especially when you plan to use several external components libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://stenciljs.com/docs/react.

```js
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'my-lib/loader';

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements();
});
```

You can also use [`@stencil/react-output-target`](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/tree/master/packages/react-output-target) to automatically generate bindings for all your components (see https://stenciljs.com/docs/react#bindings), so that if you have `my-component`, it'll generate a `MyComponent` wrapper for you that is a real React component.

---

Regarding your import error, you can probably import it as

```js
import myLib from 'my-lib';
const { MyComponent } = myLib.Components;
```